# Redirect from IP Address to Domain

Tags: apache, redirect, virtualhost

I have a plain webpage (no CMS). If I go to mydomain.com, it displays my webpage, as it should. However, if I go to my server's IP address, it displays my page as well but in the address bar, it still shows my server's IP address. How can I make it so that if I enter the IP address, it automatically redirects you to my page's domain name using the virtual host entry (not the .htaccess file)? My current vhost entry looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com
    ServerName mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mod_rewrite`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx$ #replace your IP here
RewriteRule .* http://www.yourdomain.com [R,L]
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I get a "FAILED" error message when trying to reload Apache. Is there a way to do it using Redirect instead of mod_rewrite?

Comment: Maybe you haven't enabled `mod_rewrite` module. Or, any syntax errors? I think you can also use server-side script or Javascript to redirect.

Comment: OK, I had to restart Apache (not just reload it) but it worked. Thanks!